# type error in making model using MultinonialNB

Tags: data-science-model

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[90], line 2
1 mb=MultinomialNB()
----> 2 mb.fit(x_train_idf,y_train)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py:753, in *BaseDiscreteNB.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
750 *, n_features = X.shape
752 labelbin = LabelBinarizer()
--> 753 Y = labelbin.fit_transform(y)
754 self.classes* = labelbin.classes*
755 if Y.shape[1] == 1:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_set_output.py:140, in _wrap_method_output..wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
138 @wraps(f)
139 def wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
--> 140     data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
141     if isinstance(data_to_wrap, tuple):
142         # only wrap the first output for cross decomposition
143         return (
144             _wrap_data_with_container(method, data_to_wrap[0], X, self),
145             *data_to_wrap[1:],
146         )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_label.py:334, in LabelBinarizer.fit_transform(self, y)
314 def fit_transform(self, y):
315     """Fit label binarizer/transform multi-class labels to binary labels.
316
317     The output of transform is sometimes referred to as
(...)
332         will be of CSR format.
333     """
--> 334     return self.fit(y).transform(y)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_label.py:301, in LabelBinarizer.fit(self, y)
294 if self.sparse_output and (self.pos_label == 0 or self.neg_label != 0):
295     raise ValueError(
296         "Sparse binarization is only supported with non "
297         "zero pos_label and zero neg_label, got "
298         f"pos_label={self.pos_label} and neg_label={self.neg_label}"
299     )
--> 301 self.y_type_ = type_of_target(y, input_name="y")
303 if "multioutput" in self.y_type_:
304     raise ValueError(
305         "Multioutput target data is not supported with label binarization"
306     )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py:386, in type_of_target(y, input_name)
384 # Check multiclass
385 first_row = y[0] if not issparse(y) else y.getrow(0).data
--> 386 if xp.unique_values(y).shape[0] > 2 or (y.ndim == 2 and len(first_row) > 1):
387     # [1, 2, 3] or [[1., 2., 3]] or [[1, 2]]
388     return "multiclass" + suffix
389 else:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_array_api.py:84, in _NumPyApiWrapper.unique_values(self, x)
83 def unique_values(self, x):
---> 84     return numpy.unique(x)

File <**array_function** internals>:180, in unique(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py:274, in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis, equal_nan)
272 ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
273 if axis is None:
--> 274     ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts,
275                     equal_nan=equal_nan)
276     return _unpack_tuple(ret)
278 # axis was specified and not None

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py:336, in *unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, equal_nan)
334     aux = ar[perm]
335 else:
--> 336     ar.sort()
337     aux = ar
338 mask = np.empty(aux.shape, dtype=np.bool*)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody will be able to help you if you only show us an error message. We would need to see what piece of code exactly triggered this, and some example data. ALso, please use the code formatting tool in the question interface, currently it is a mess.